# Navigator - SceneConfig Is It Possible To Have 'No' Transition?

Tags: react-native

Being able to use animated transitions is awesome in Navigator. But I want to be able to flip between routes without animation and just have it quickly pop there like you would with a Tab Bar. Like 1 frame it's route A and in the next frame it's route B.

Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid comes close, but if I just simply accelerate the animation it has this undesirable flicker effect.

What would a non-animated SceneConfig look like?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a custom NoTransition.js:

```
import { Navigator } from 'react-native'
import buildStyleInterpolator from 'buildStyleInterpolator' // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies

// Based on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1953#issuecomment-209872368

const NoTransition = {
  opacity: {
    type: 'constant',
    value: 1.0,
  },
}

export default Object.assign({}, Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid, {
  animationInterpolators: {
    into: buildStyleInterpolator(NoTransition),
    out: buildStyleInterpolator(NoTransition),
  },
  defaultTransitionVelocity: 1000,
  gestures: null,
})
```

Return it from `Navigator`'s `configureScene` prop to use.